# Temporal evolution of the mean value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

[image]

**Using the above, demonstrate that the temporal evolution of the mean value of a time-independent
operator that has the same eigenfunctions as the Hamiltonian is zero.**

If the operator is time-independent, then dO/dt = zero.

I am stuck as to what I do from here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $\hat{O}$ has the same eigenfunctions as $\hat{H}$, what can you say about their commutator $[\hat{O}, \hat{H}]$?

Comment: Is it equal to 0 as well?

Comment: Try the following: since $\hat{O}$ and $\hat{H}$ have the same eigenfunctions, consider the action of $[\hat{O}, \hat{H}] = \hat{O}\hat{H} - \hat{H}\hat{O}$ on any such eigenfunction. Make sure to use the definition of eigenfunction: $\hat{O}|\psi\rangle = \lambda|\psi\rangle$.